# VS2010 Compile Button

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have looked to see if I can find a "compile" button in VS2010 but can not find one.  I do have a build, buildwebsite, and rebuildwebsite button.   Does a build do the same thing as compile in VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, building means compiling in VS.

You can also use `Ctrl+Shift+B` to build.

Rebuild basically means clean + compile.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I figure this had to be the same but you thought I had better ask to make sure...   I appreciate it!